# How to retrieve IMSI using PhoneGap?

Tags: mobile, cordova

I'm working on a cross platform mobile app using PhoneGap and I need to retrieve the IMSI code.

Here's the question: Is there any way to do this via PhoneGap?

I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 1):

hi  for android we can find via native code , for phonegap we need to write a plugin, java code is given bellow

```
 public String findDeviceID() {
     String deviceID = null;
     String serviceName = Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE;
     TelephonyManager m_telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(serviceName);
     int deviceType = m_telephonyManager.getPhoneType();
     switch (deviceType) {
         case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM):
             break;
         case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA):
             break;
         case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE):
             break;
         default:
             break;
     }
     deviceID = m_telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
     return deviceID;
 }
```

for creating phonegap plugin check this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins

Comment: Hi Raj, Thanks for your reply. I know that it's possible to create a plugin to do that , but as I mentioned in the question I'm working on a cross platform application so the problem of this solution is that I have to make same plugin for iOS, Windows Mobile and etc.